# Kendo does not show any data Also it shows a blank row in mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bootstrap-4

Kendo does not show any data and it shows a blank row.
The grid reads from a controller method, which returns JSON. I have verified that the controller method is returning the correct, valid JSON, but the grid only shows the column titles, without any data in the table's rows with one blank row. It shows a ReferenceError: kendo is not defined And at Console it shows Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:56644/Content/css/bootstrap-reboot.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap-reboot.css.map

```
 public ActionResult GetProductsLists([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request )        
 {
       var product = (from u in this.unitOfWork.Product.Get()
              select new ProductViewModel
              {
                  product_id = u.product_id,
                  product_name = u.product_name
              });

    DataSourceResult result = product.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="grid class="kendo-grid-custom">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductViewModel>()
                                        .Name("gridProduct")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(c => c.product_id).Title("Product Id").Filterable(true);
                                            columns.Bound(c => c.product_name).Title("Product Name").Filterable(true)                                         
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%;" })
                                            .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-nowrap" })
                                            .Scrollable()
                                            .Sortable()
                                            .Filterable()
                                            .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
                                            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                            .Refresh(true)
                                            .PageSizes(true)
                                            .ButtonCount(5)
                                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax().Sort(x => x.Add("product_id").Ascending())
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductList", "Product"))
                                            .Model(m =>
                                            {
                                                m.Id(i => i.product_id);
                                            }).PageSize("20"))
                )

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bundling issue. Show your references.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult GetProductsLists([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request )        
   {
      var product = (from u in this.unitOfWork.Product.Get()
                  select new ProductViewModel
                  {
                      product_id = u.product_id,
                      product_name = u.product_name
                  });

        DataSourceResult result = product.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

change your controller function using **DataSourceRequest** object and return the json result

Comment: Yes I do that but does not show any data and it shows a blank row & the controller method is returning the correct, valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes there is a bundling issue. Actually I gave the wrong Path of Kendo references thats 
why my kendo does not show any data. So I fix it and give it the right path i.e                                                                                 
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.custom.css"));

Also I crosscheck the path of the kendo script through the solution explorer as well as local disk of my computer.
```